# Make Airflow custom operator compliant with Taskflow API

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I just discovered the Taskflow API by watching the Airflow summit 2022.

It works fine, but I still heavily rely on "classic" operators, some of them I have written myself.

Is there documentation that explains how I could make my custom operators compliant with the Taskflow API?
I guess that would mean:

- not relying on bitwise syntax for dependency
- not relying on .output to get to the return values of my operators

Comment: I've found some documentation about it here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.4/howto/create-custom-decorator.html

Comment: @LucaSoato I guess that would work, but creating a provider package might be overkill for my usecase. Also I'm not sure how that would work with operators that don't take callables

Comment: I've been wondering this as well. Almost all of my operators are custom. Since Airflow 2 was released it feels like there are two pretty different ways of doing Airflow and I'm still wondering how/if they will come together in the end. 

I also don't want to create a provider package, for now having my children of BaseOperator in a few imported files has worked well for me.

Comment: It seems like they're continuing to work on TaskFlow, and it's a lot further along now. One of the biggest remaining differences is of course that a class descended from BaseOperator is a class, not a function, so you would usually implement both the constructor and `execute()`. But it seems like they could somehow map the constructor to `override()` (the method already used on decorated task functions to override things like `task_id`), and `execute()` to what happens when the function is called. Using the class name like a function might be weird I guess, but it no longer seems impossible.

Comment: I have posted this as an Idea on the Airflow GitHub: https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/27038#discussioncomment-3873911